# Linux File Permissions lying to me

Tags: linux, files, permissions, sudo

So I am the user `david` and according to `ls -la` the file permissions are `700` and the owner is david. I can not understand why I am not allowed to write to the file. The `stat` command returns something interesting that there are 2 `Access:` one for 700 and one for 500. The `500` would explain why I can't write to the file but why doesn't that show up when I do `ls -la`? Also I am not able to `sudo` anything since I do not know the password for `david`

```
david@traverxec:~/bin$ ls -la
total 16
drwx------ 2 david david 4096 Mar  1 17:43 .
drwx--x--x 5 david david 4096 Oct 25 17:02 ..
-r-------- 1 david david  802 Oct 25 16:26 server-stats.head
-rwx------ 1 david david  363 Oct 25 16:26 server-stats.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Mar  1 17:43 test
david@traverxec:~/bin$ stat server-stats.sh 
  File: server-stats.sh
  Size: 363             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 10901       Links: 1
Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/   david)   Gid: ( 1000/   david)
Access: 2020-03-01 17:27:22.389179535 -0500
Modify: 2019-10-25 16:26:29.049613415 -0400
Change: 2019-10-27 16:24:21.437108121 -0400
 Birth: -
david@traverxec:~/bin$ echo "test" >> server-stats.sh 
-bash: server-stats.sh: Operation not permitted
david@traverxec:~/bin$ id
uid=1000(david) gid=1000(david) groups=1000(david),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev)
```

Edit:
I am able to make files within the directory. I'm not too sure but it doesn't seem like it is mounted from somewhere else... hmmm

```
david@traverxec:~/bin$ touch test
david@traverxec:~/bin$ ls -la
total 16
drwx------ 2 david david 4096 Mar  1 17:43 .
drwx--x--x 5 david david 4096 Oct 25 17:02 ..
-r-------- 1 david david  802 Oct 25 16:26 server-stats.head
-rwx------ 1 david david  363 Oct 25 16:26 server-stats.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Mar  1 17:43 test
david@traverxec:~/bin$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       3.9G  1.5G  2.3G  40% /
david@traverxec:~/bin$ findmnt -T .
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/sda1 ext4   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
david@traverxec:~/bin$
```

Comment: See if there ACLs set on the file. Or a security policy (SELinux, AppArmor, others) might forbid writing. Linux has extended permissions, files that are inmutable or apoend-only.

Comment: It's much better to use copy-paste instead of screenshots. It makes question more accessible.

Comment: Check if you have any issues with mount itself (e.g. in case of disk / FS errors the mount might be remounted with read-only permission). E.g. `mount`.

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It's very hard to read on a smaller screen.

Comment: "there are 2 `Access:` one for 700 and one for 500"  --  I only see permissions of `0700` in your `stat` output.  Where do you get permissions of `0500`?  The timezone offset in the last accessed time?

Comment: Can you write to any other files in this directory (or create a new file)?

Comment: Please edit to show output of `findmnt -T .`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I updated the post to include findmnt and df -h but still am unsure about why this is happening :/

Comment: @rush Sorry about that I just edited the post

Comment: Is the immutable bit set? Run lsattr server-stats.sh if it’s set ‘i’ will appear it the output attributes.

Comment: Post output of `ls -Z server-stats.sh` to check for extra permissions

Comment: Mmm ok. Theory shot down in flames

Comment: @EnterUserNameHere Took the W here. The file is marked as immutable. Should have checked that before

Comment: @DL_Engineer: I tried to reproduce but I got `bash: file: Permission denied` instead of `Operation not permitted` with `GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)`. What is your Bash version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:
The file is marked as immutable which means that not even root can modify this file

```
david@traverxec:~/bin$ lsattr server-stats.sh 
----i---------e---- server-stats.sh
```

Fix:
This fix won't work for me since I do not have root/sudo access but here it is for anyone else

```
sudo chattr -i server-stats.sh
```

Comment: Can you copy it, and rename the directory?